# How to set HTML to clipboard in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, html, clipboard

I want to put rich text in HTML on the clipboard so when the users paste to Word, it will include the source HTML formatting.

Using [the `Clipboard.SetText` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbfb3z56.aspx) doesn't work.

Also, I would like that if users paste into a rich editor like Word it will paste formatted text, and if they paste into a plain editor like Notepad it will paste plain text.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When setting HTML text, you need to provide a header with additional information to what fragment of the html you actually want to paste while being able to provide additional styling around it:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:000125
EndHTML:000260
StartFragment:000209
EndFragment:000222
<HTML>
<head>
<title>HTML clipboard</title>
</head>
<body>
<!–StartFragment–><b>Hello!</b><!–EndFragment–>
</body>
</html>
```

With the header (and correct indexes), calling `Clipboard.SetText` with `TextDataFormat.Html` will do the trick.

To handle HTML and plain text pastes, you can’t use the `Clipboard.SetText` method, as it clears the clipboard each time it’s called; you need to create a `DataObject` instance, call its `SetData` method once with HTML and once with plain text, and then set the object to clipboard using `Clipboard.SetDataObject`.

**Update**

See "[Setting HTML/Text to Clipboard revisited](http://theartofdev.com/2014/06/12/setting-htmltext-to-clipboard-revisited/)" for more details and *ClipboardHelper* implementation.

Comment: Read linked post, it's worth it!

Comment: Great stuff, however it and several other solutions I have found do not seem to put anything into the HTML formatted clipboard. It just remains empty, even if the data object appears to have the correct formatting for it's html.

Comment: The actual numbers in the header seem completely wrong. It is entirely unclear to me how these numbers are calculated and every article I found, including this, failed to explain this. The best I could find was cryptic code that doesn't help either.

Comment: @ygoe -- [The Page Linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917(v=vs.85).aspx) by Chris Thornton appears to answer the question of how these header numbers are set.

Comment: @ygoe -- Indeed, I just tried using this technique myself, and the numbers are just byte offsets from the beginning of the text. Padding the numbers at the left is recommended so that when the values are set the offsets remain correct. That is, use a placeholder like 012345 and then replace those placeholders after evaluating the final offsets, such as by using IndexOf() or similar functions, but be sure to use the same number of characters for the values, hence padding with zero.

Answer (score 7):

I found some code: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21966855/Create-a-hyperlink-in-VB-net-copy-to-clipboard-Should-be-able-to-paste-hyperlink-in-Microsoft-Word-Excel.html

This code handles the problems of updating the start and end indexes.

Converted to c#:

```
public void AddHyperlinkToClipboard(string link, string description)
{
    const string sContextStart = "<HTML><BODY><!--StartFragment -->";
    const string sContextEnd = "<!--EndFragment --></BODY></HTML>";
    const string m_sDescription = "Version:1.0" + Constants.vbCrLf + "StartHTML:aaaaaaaaaa" + Constants.vbCrLf + "EndHTML:bbbbbbbbbb" + Constants.vbCrLf + "StartFragment:cccccccccc" + Constants.vbCrLf + "EndFragment:dddddddddd" + Constants.vbCrLf;

    string sHtmlFragment = "<A HREF=" + Strings.Chr(34) + link + Strings.Chr(34) + ">" + description + "</A>";

    string sData = m_sDescription + sContextStart + sHtmlFragment + sContextEnd;
    sData = sData.Replace("aaaaaaaaaa", m_sDescription.Length.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0'));
    sData = sData.Replace("bbbbbbbbbb", sData.Length.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0'));
    sData = sData.Replace("cccccccccc", (m_sDescription + sContextStart).Length.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0'));
    sData = sData.Replace("dddddddddd", (m_sDescription + sContextStart + sHtmlFragment).Length.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0'));
    sData.Dump();
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(new DataObject(DataFormats.Html, sData), true );
}
```

Comment: I also added to "true" to SetDataObject to keep the contents on the clipboard after the thread exits.

Comment: The calculations work well for basic ASCII charset, but it needs to be: Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(sData).ToString().PadLeft(10, '0') instead of sData.Length.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0')
in order not to corrupt when there are wider characters used.

Answer (score 4):

Let me share a helper for setting the clipboard data as HTML, which I've just come up with for my little side project [#DevComrade](https://github.com/postprintum/devcomrade#what-is-it):

```cs
var dataObject = new DataObject();
dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Html, ClipboardFormats.ConvertHtmlToClipboardData(html);
Host.SetClipboardDataObject(dataObject);

internal static class ClipboardFormats
{
    static readonly string HEADER = 
        "Version:0.9\r\n" +
        "StartHTML:{0:0000000000}\r\n" +
        "EndHTML:{1:0000000000}\r\n" +
        "StartFragment:{2:0000000000}\r\n" +
        "EndFragment:{3:0000000000}\r\n";

    static readonly string HTML_START =
        "<html>\r\n" +
        "<body>\r\n" +
        "<!--StartFragment-->";

    static readonly string HTML_END =
        "<!--EndFragment-->\r\n" +
        "</body>\r\n" +
        "</html>";

    public static string ConvertHtmlToClipboardData(string html)
    {
        var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false);
        var data = Array.Empty<byte>();

        var header = encoding.GetBytes(String.Format(HEADER, 0, 1, 2, 3));
        data = data.Concat(header).ToArray();

        var startHtml = data.Length;
        data = data.Concat(encoding.GetBytes(HTML_START)).ToArray();

        var startFragment = data.Length;
        data = data.Concat(encoding.GetBytes(html)).ToArray();

        var endFragment = data.Length;
        data = data.Concat(encoding.GetBytes(HTML_END)).ToArray();

        var endHtml = data.Length;

        var newHeader = encoding.GetBytes(
            String.Format(HEADER, startHtml, endHtml, startFragment, endFragment));
        if (newHeader.Length != startHtml)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(ConvertHtmlToClipboardData));
        }

        Array.Copy(newHeader, data, length: startHtml);
        return encoding.GetString(data);
    } 
}
```

I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/add-html-code-clipboard) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767917(v=vs.85)) references. Also, kudos @DaveyBoy for spotting a bug.

Comment: I believe there's a mistake in this line:
 var newHeader = encoding.GetBytes(
            String.Format(HEADER, startHtml, startFragment, endFragment, endHtml));

Pretty sure this should be:
var newHeader = encoding.GetBytes(
                string.Format(cbHeader, startHtml, endHtml, startFragment, endFragment));

I wasn't able to get it to paste into Outlook or Word without that fix (but MSTeams took it just fine, for some reason).   When I looked at the actual string we had built, I realized that the endHtml value was way too small.

Comment: Coming back to this.. oh yeah, I see now what you mean - fixed! 

Answer (score 1):

Arthur is right about the header, but the important thing to note here is that the data isn't going to be on the clipboard as plain text. You have to use CF_HTML. You can read about that at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917(v=vs.85).aspx
To be proper, you'd have a CF_TEXT showing simply: "Hello!", and then CF_HTML with the HTML header and data, as in Arthur's example.

Answer (score -1):

As Arthur had mentioned I used the code at [Setting HTML/Text to Clipboard revisited](https://theartofdev.com/2014/06/12/setting-htmltext-to-clipboard-revisited/)

I had to add linefeeds to the Header to get it to work (in this case VB)

```
Private Const Header As String = "Version:0.9" & vbCrLf & "StartHTML:<<<<<<<<1" & vbCrLf & "EndHTML:<<<<<<<<2" & vbCrLf & "StartFragment:<<<<<<<<3" & vbCrLf & "EndFragment:<<<<<<<<4" & vbCrLf & "StartSelection:<<<<<<<<3" & vbCrLf & "EndSelection:<<<<<<<<4"
```

Hope this helps