# Copying HTML text to clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, html, clipboard, copy-paste, data-formats

I've got the following problem: Copying the content of a html file (*.htm) with the clipboard function this way works very well, but the content is not formatted - I get the html tags like br, body or html with my text.

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, (Object)Inhalt);
```

Here is the solution I found on the internet:

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Html, (Object)Inhalt);
```

**Inhalt** is a `string`. Unfortunately it does not copy my text, but there is no error message. What is my fallacy?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332377/how-to-set-html-text-in-clipboard)... you need to put a header on the string.

Comment: Also here's [a blog post about it](http://theartofdev.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/setting-html-and-plain-text-formatting-to-clipboard/) with a code sample.

Comment: You should make that an actual answer so people can vote for it.

Comment: Is there another easier way to do that? (Thanks so far for your help.)

Comment: @curtisrutland I would've except it seemed an almost exact duplicate. To OP, unfortunately no, I don't know any easier way. But if you write a method to do this you can re-use it whenever you need, and the code sample I linked should provide a decent start.