# Customize copied/pasted content depending on target

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

I have noticed that many applications copy and paste differently depending on the target application. For instance, if I "HTML copy" an item in TFS (in the web interface):

- if I paste it in notepad, I get a csv-like output
- if I paste it in Excel, I get nicely formatted rows and columns
- if I paste it in Outlook, I get a nice-looking table

I have tried to use multiple instances of `Clipboard.SetText(String, TextDataFormat)` with different `TextDataFormat` values, but alas, they overwrite each other (and anything but `TextDataFormat.Text` doesn't seem to "allow" pasting).

What I have tried so far:

```
private static void KeyPressed(KeyEventArgs e, GridView grid)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        var textContent = new StringBuilder();
        var htmlContent = new StringBuilder("<table>");

        // build content
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            htmlContent.AppendFormat("<tr><td>{0}</td></tr>", i);
            textContent.AppendFormat("{0}\t", i);
        }

        textContent.Length--; // remove last tab
        htmlContent.Append("</table>");

        // send contents to clipboard
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetText(textContent.ToString(), TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue);
        Clipboard.SetText(textContent.ToString(), TextDataFormat.Text);
        Clipboard.SetText(htmlContent.ToString(), TextDataFormat.Html);

        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need the following:

```
var dataObject = new DataObject(textContent); // allows data to auto-convert on paste
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, it always copies as text. I have also tried `Clipboard.SetDataObject(new DataObject("Html", htmlContent.ToString()));` but it doesn't "allow" pasting.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I searched more and found an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332377/how-to-set-html-to-clipboard-in-c

Comment: Glad I was able to point you in the right direction.