# Correct header for copying HTML on the clipboard

Tags: c#, html, .net, clipboard

I have a complete HTML document and need to copy it on the clipboard so that it can be pasted into Microsoft Word and other applications. Now I figured out that the obvious way doesn't work and I need to add a special header before the HTML content. Unfortunately all samples seem to show invalid header data so that I can't learn from it. And all I can find is cryptic sample code that handles all sorts of complicated use cases, still that doesn't help me. And there isn't a readable explanation of the header numbers anywhere.

So here's a sample HTML document that I have as string in .NET:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If this fragment thing is really required, I might add those comments in my document just inside the `<body>` element.

The header is supposed to look somehow like this:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:1
EndHTML:2
StartFragment:3
EndFragment:4
StartSelection:3
EndSelection:4
```

What are the correct numbers for 1, 2, 3, and 4? How are they calculated, considering UTF-8 encoding and all that's required? Please provide a plain text description or algorithm, or simple C# code for only this simple case, nothing fancy with bells and whistles. I can adapt from there.

Comment: It would help if you could point to the cryptic examples you've seen.  Normally the clipboard format is stored separately from the data itself.

Comment: I think you're referring to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649015(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that the CF_HTML clipboard format is an example of the clipboard format I referred to.  The data on the clipboard has to both be text in the correct format AND with this type or it will just be pasted as a text string.

Comment: BTW, that page has the description of all the fields in the header, so I think this is what you want.

Comment: These are the articles I have read, after turning away from the MSDN documentation: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2007/01/21/copying-html-on-the-clipboard/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332377/how-to-set-html-to-clipboard-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out that the fragment thing is not required. The header has the following numbers:

- 1 and 3: The length of the header itself (zero-padding is necessary to achieve predictable results, otherwise the header length changes after putting in the numbers, making the numbers invalid)
- 2 and 4: The length of the header + the number of UTF-8 bytes of the entire HTML document

This can be pasted into Word and Excel. No fragments or HTML comments required.

Sample C# code:

```
int start = header.Length;
int end = header.Length + Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(html);
```