# How do I copy text to the clipboard with partial italics?

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, copy-paste, clipboarddata

How do I make it so that txtTitleofWebpage.Text is in italics when copied to the Clipboard so that the user can copy the references into a Microsoft Word document? I'm trying to make a Windows Form Application using C# to generate Harvard References from information the user inputs into a form.

Here is the code:

```
Clipboard.SetText(wholeName + ", (" + yOPDate + ") " + txtTitleofWebpage.Text + 
                  " [online]. Available from: " + txtURLWeb.Text + " [Accessed: " + 
                  accessDateWeb.Value.ToShortDateString() + "].", TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

Comment: Well, not that way.  You need to use a format that can specify typographic styles and is compatible with whatever app you want to paste into.  HTML and Rich text (RTF) are common choices.  Google "c# copy html to clipboard", the top hits are all existing SO questions.

Comment: @HansPassant - So, I can set TextDataFormat to HTML. Though, I find if I add an italics opening and closing tag around txtTitleofWebpages.Text I get errors.

Comment: add @ in front of the opening and closing tags, this will ignore escape characters which they might be seen as. Like: `@"This \n will not make a newline"`

Comment: @EpicKip So, like this...? `Clipboard.SetText(@<body> wholeName + ", (" + yOPDate + ") " + @<i> txtTitleofWebpage.Text @</i> + " [online]. Available from: " + txtURLWeb.Text + " [Accessed: " + accessDateWeb.Value.ToShortDateString() + "]." @</body>, TextDataFormat.Html);`

Comment: @HansPassant - The text will be pasted into a Word Document.

Comment: @EpicKip - The text will be pasted into a Word Document.

Comment: @jamesfromit <body> is not in quotes, it should be because its not "text" until you put it in quotes. And @ only works in front of a " to escape special characters from that string.

Comment: @jamesfromit Ok, I can easily help you if you just provide me an example string (which is not working) instead of string names. I can't detect the problem without their value.

Comment: @EpicKip - Nothing seems to be copying to the Clipboard. Here is the code: `Clipboard.SetText(@"<body>" + wholeName + ", (" + yOPDate + ") " + @"<i>" + txtTitleofWebpage.Text + @"</i>" + " [online]. Available from: " + txtURLWeb.Text + " [Accessed: " + accessDateWeb.Value.ToShortDateString() + "]. </body>", TextDataFormat.Html);`

Comment: Ok this time change the variables (txtURLWeb) to some test data so I can use it. I cant do anything if you don't provide me the values. Its going wrong around there haha. Does it even give an error?

Comment: @EpicKip - This is what it's supposed to be formatted as: Nightingale, J, (13/01/2017) _Title of Webpage in Italics_ [online]. Available from: http://www.google.co.uk/ [Accessed: 03/02/2017].

Comment: @EpicKip - No, it doesn't give any errors.

Comment: @jamesfromit It doesn't copy because of TextDataFormat.Html, I can tell you that much. I'm looking for a way to copy the formatting along. Hold on a sec :)

Comment: @EpicKip - Okay, thank you. I have plenty of time to work on this. :)

Comment: @jamesfromit My break is starting now, I left 2 links that might fix your problem. I'll try and find the answer later if I have time.

Comment: @EpicKip - Thank you! :)

Comment: @jamesfromit Edited my answer with a code sample and some things to try. If its working please let me know :)

Comment: @jamesfromit Check my last edit for RTF

Comment: @jamesfromit If my answer fixed it/helped you the best could you accept it?

Comment: @EpicKip - Yeah, I will totally accept it. I just haven't had the time to try it yet. College is getting in the way. :)

Comment: @jamesfromit I can test it anymore today as my workday is done and I wont be at a computer tonight so I hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to insert a 'header' in the html string, I found 2 examples for this:

- [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2007/01/21/copying-html-on-the-clipboard/)
- [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332377/how-to-set-html-to-clipboard-in-c)

This works with Word:
**Example code:**

```
    Clipboard.SetText(@"Version:1.0
                        StartHTML:000125
                        EndHTML:000260
                        StartFragment:000209
                        EndFragment:000222
                        <HTML>
                        <head>
                        <title>HTML clipboard</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <!–StartFragment–><b>Hello!</b><!–EndFragment–>
                        </body>
                        </html>", 
                        TextDataFormat.Html);
```

This copies a **Hello!** to your clipboard, you have to change the fragments based on the size I think so I don't know exactly how that would work with a dynamic string but I hope this will get you started.  666

**If you can also use RTF**

```
Clipboard.SetText(@"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \i\f0\fs17 italic\i0.}",
                    TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

**Example with string**

```
var q = "test123";
Clipboard.SetText(@"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \i\f0\fs17 " + q + @"\i0.}",
                    TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

*[or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)*

```
var q = "test123";
Clipboard.SetText( $@"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \i\f0\fs17 {q}\i0.}",
                    TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

*Note the `@` before the 2nd part of the string, if you need to escape certain characters (you will need that with **RTF**) add `@` in front of each opening `"`.*

This seems to be a lot easier because you don't have to insert the header but the formatting itself is abit more complicated imo.

Comment: @DownVoter(s) please leave a comment as to why my answer is wrong instead of just downvoting it. The question I linked to described exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I go about doing this with RTF?

Comment: `TextDataFormat.Rtf`? And obviously make the formatting in the string Rtf

Comment: You might not even need a header of sorts for that.

Comment: That RTF works but how would I make it work with variables and strings from textBox.Text?

Comment: @jamesfromit Glad I could help