# Prepare text to paste to MS Word with proper alignment

Tags: c#, vba, winforms, ms-word, rtf

I am working on a C# application that calculates some values. They are placed into a DataGridView. When I select values from a column of the DataGridView and I paste them to a column of a table from a Word document, I want the values to be center aligned. Even if I set all cells of the DataGridView to be center aligned, when I copy and paste the text into the Word table, they show up left aligned.
The code used to copy the table into clipboard is

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(this.dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
```

How can I prepare the text so that when I paste it, it will show centered? If I copy and paste text from another column of Word, it maintains the original alignment. This indicates there are some special characters surrounding the cell values. I don't know how to view those characters (maybe I can add them to each value).

Comment: First off, this may or may not be obvious to you but this a Microsoft Word question (assuming you're actually using Word to edit a "Word document" not say libre office).  Second, solving this will require knowledge of Microsoft Word cut and paste mechanics that more specifically go beyond mere "plain text" because plain text by itself doesn't know or care about centering (aside from contained whitespace).  If I think a bit this will imply better tag's for this question... I hope.  For starters VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) or word macros may be related.

Comment: [This link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6) may help in your case.

Comment: Thanks ebyrob for comments. I just noticed that the tag "word" is not about MS Word, as I was expecting. I will change the tags (somebody else did it already).

Comment: Thanks Keyur, I found that document before posting the question, but I want to set the proper format from the application, not from MS Word.

Comment: @Nick_F I've been adjusting your tags if that's OK, a second change is pending review.  This is the only question I'm looking at right now, but I am pretty slow and almost entirely unfamiliar with VBA (though I know someone really good at it I can ask tomorrow if need be)  I changed word to `ms-word` and added `rtf` and `vba`.  I think Rich Text Format may well be pastable into Word which would be very helpful I hope in the general case, though I don't know for sure it'll work for tables but if it does, then bless that wealthy speed-demon guy and those that followed.

Comment: Thanks ebyrob. I'm not in a hurry, we can adjust the alignment manually when we use the application. It's a minor problem, but it can be improved. Maybe somebody who knows how to do it will come across this question.

Comment: I was able to see what's being actually copied to clipboard when I select two cells from a Word table. I used Ultraedit editor and selected Paste Special - Raw RTF. For two small numbers stored in two cells, there are over 40000 bytes of information. That's what I call bloating!  I think it may be possible to use a RichTextBox to format my column before pasting into MS-Word. If I succeed, I will post some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to cheat and start with an incomplete answer.

This RTF text seems like it should work for a single value:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\qc
This is some centered text.}
```

That's a "hard newline" after `\qc` or I think just a `\n`.  If I put that RTF into a file then open in WordPad it shows up centered.

I've been playing with `System.Windows.Forms.ClipBoard`.

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, "{\\rtf1\\qc\n{\\b foo}}");
```

If I run the above even in a console application, I can next ctrl-V paste into MS Word and the **bold** works, but unfortunately the centering doesn't.

In any case, I then looked at pasting into a MS Word table and clearly it's not just a matter of text with newlines, some delimiter or other is required to show cell boundaries.  So not only does the RTF I have not work, there's likely at least one more step / wrapper beyond the RTF to get a "column" not just a block of text.

Feel free to not vote, I just thought perhaps something here might be helpful to avoid both of us doing the same thing twice.

**EDIT:** `DataFormats.Html` may also work and seems it could even be the format normally used by your grid control.  (though it also supports CSV)

However there's an extra clipboard header for HTML I haven't figured out yet described here:  [How to set HTML to clipboard in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332377/how-to-set-html-to-clipboard-in-c)

Comment: Thanks ebyrob, your line of code was essential. I will explain how I solved it. I used MS Word in conjunction with WordPad. Wordpad generates much cleaner RTF code. However, it has limited features (at least I don't know how to create a table in Wordpad) so I copied a column from a MS Word Table and I pasted it into Wordpad. From there, I used Paste Special - Raw RTF into Ultraedit. That code has all the formatting required and it can be used as a template string which can be populated with a number of cells. We can add extra rows as desired.

Comment: @Nick_F It would be AWESOME If you put that into an answer on this thread.  That is something I really want to up-vote.  Sorry for being so lazy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I will post my solution in here, so it can be used (and improved) by other people. We need to place a populated dataGridView object on form and a button. The button calls function CopyColumn(). I have some problems to properly format the code (some of the long strings are separated as text by stackoverflow, maybe somebody will help with including them into code.

```
    void CopyColumn()
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(this.dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());

                string sText = Clipboard.GetText();
                string sColumn = FormatColumn(sText);

                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, sColumn); // this will set the proper format of the Uncertainty column in clipboard memory 
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Clipboard could not be accessed. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    string FormatColumn(string sValues)
    {
        int nlines = NumLines(sValues);
        string[] values = Values(sValues);

        string sStart = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang3081{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
```

{*\generator Riched20 10.0.14393}\viewkind4\uc1";

```
        string sEnd = "}";

        string sRowStart = @"\trowd\trgaph85\trleft5\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trpaddl85\trpaddr85\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3
```

\clvertalc\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx1706 
\pard\intbl\widctlpar\qc ";

```
        string sRowEnd = @"\cell\row";

        string sFormattedColumn = sStart;
        string sRow = string.Empty;

        for(int i = 0; i < nlines; i++) {
            sRow = sRowStart + values[i] + sRowEnd;
            sFormattedColumn += sRow;
        }

        sFormattedColumn += sEnd;
        return sFormattedColumn;
    }

    int NumLines(string sValue)
    {
        string[] values = sValue.Split('\r');
        return values.Length;
    }

    string[] Values(string sValue)
    {
        string[] values = sValue.Split('\r');
        for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
            values[i] = values[i].Replace("\n", "");
        }

        return values;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fear this is not related to your VBA, but a bug in MS Word (tested for 2010 and 2016).
It's enough to do the following (not sure it's the same bug you're suffering from):
1. Open a new Word doc.
2. Insert a table (let's say 4 columns, 4 rows).
3. Mark all cells and format them as centered.
4. Type some text into a cell, select it and copy it.
Now there are two scenarios:
A: Paste the copied text into **a single** free cell -> The pasted text is **centered**, as expected.
B: Mark **several adjacent** free cells and paste the text -> The pasted text is **left-aligned** instead of centered!!
If I use LibreOffice (which I recommend to you, too), all this works fine (no surprise).
No, I did not pay for MS Office, but I have to use it at work :/

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I could replicate your test. When we choose to center the text in a cell, an invisible character gets added to that cell. If we click on an empty cell, the cursor is placed on center. If we press Backspace, the Center format will disappear and the cursor will get to the left. When we select multiple cells (to paste into), that hidden character is also being selected and replaced by data in the clipboard. In your case, if you copy the text of your source cell using Shift + End, that hidden character for Center gets copied as well and you can paste to multiple rows.